# How to solve this limit problem using the definition?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I don't know how to start this problem or either solve it. Would much appreciate if someone can help me out with this. **Thanks!**

Only interested in part a)

Problem at the link below:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYeAW.jpg)

Comment: I see nothing following your incomplete sentence: "Only interested in part a) ...."

Comment: Oh, and just in case you haven't known this:  MSE is **not** a "do my work for me" site.  I'm sure you'll find a handful of sites where folks will do your work for, but at a cost to you.  Don't abuse this site consisting of strictly volunteers.

Comment: Wow, thanks for being so kind and polite!

Comment: Your welcome, Synotax!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition of a limit - the values of the function have to approach the limiting value (in this case 2) from both the left and right directions. The limit as $x \to 1$ is not 2 because when approaching from the left, $f$ is equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks! But how to more in mathematically notation represent the answer?

Comment: You might say that $\lim_{x \to 1^+} = 2$, and $\lim_{x \to 1^-} = 0$ - since the left and right hand limits don't match, the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $L=\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$ exists. Then, for $\epsilon=1$, there is $ \delta >0$ such that $|x-1| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<1$.

If $x \ge 1$ and $|x-1| < \delta$, we get $|2-L|<1,$ hence $L>1$.

If $x < 1$ and $|x-1| < \delta$, we get $|L|<1,$ hence $L<1$, a contradiction.